# LAMP Server - index.php not loading when domain calls

Tags: php, lamp

So I have a working lamp server.

I have php installed and can call the php files when called directly.

However, index.php will not load when the domain is called.

http://www.AnthonyRussell.info

doesnt work. However,

http://www.AnthonyRussell.info/index.php

Does.

I think i have to add a reference somewhere but I can't seem to find it or what or where it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html

`DirectoryIndex Directive` in .htaccess file with value index.php solve your problem

Comment: Yeah that was what I found but I cant find the .htaccess file